Does DynamoDB Lock Client have to trust the client about lock expiry?
DynamoDB supports distributed locking thanks to its atomic conditional writes, but I'm not clear exactly how that works. The docs for the DDB lock client say

The lock client never stores absolute times in DynamoDB -- only the relative "lease duration" time is stored in DynamoDB. The way locks are expired is that a call to acquireLock reads in the current lock, checks the RecordVersionNumber of the lock (which is a GUID) and starts a timer. If the lock still has the same GUID after the lease duration time has passed, the client will determine that the lock is stale and expire it. What this means is that, even if two different machines disagree about what time it is, they will still avoid clobbering each other's locks.

Which sounds like the client controls expiry, and it's trusting the client not to expire the lock prematurely.
But I also see articles like this one mentioning that a call to acquire the lock uses local time like in this request:
{
  TableName: 'MyTable',
  Key: { id: 'item-123' },
  UpdateExpression: 'SET lockTime = :lockTime, lockedBy = :processId',
  ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(lockTime) OR lockTime < :now',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':lockTime': lockExpiration,
    ':processId': processId,
    ':now': now,
  },
};

It seems like the example in that second post actually is relying on all the clients to have the same notion of time, which I know isn't true. But it doesn't seem likely that the algorithm is based on trusting clients to wait for the entire leaseDuration before acquiring the lock.
But if we're trusting the client, why the lockTime < :now?  I don't see how lockTime < :now could be useful unless every computer has the same now, and even then maybe not.
Can anyone clarify how the lock expiry works?  Is the case of "one client has an expired lock, another client acquires it", what are the calls that happen?
